# Encryption of partition for dual boot setup

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I would like to get Windows 7 along Ubuntu 14.04 on separate disk partitions where Windows partition is encrypted.

What are the options to get this type of setup starting from empty disk drive?

Answer (score 0):

Partition the drive into three areas, all bootable.

First area, NTFS for your Windows 7.

Second area, for your Ubuntu 14.04.

Third area, (small), for a backup grub loader that allows both Windows and Ubuntu booting.

First, install Windows 7, and then Truecrypt (7.1a or earlier). Encrypt the windows partition with Truecrypt and create a Truecrypt rescue disk, and verify that you can boot from it and get to Windows.

Second, install Ubuntu 14.04 into the larger non NTFS partition. This WILL destroy the Windows boot loader, and you will not be able to boot Windows afterwards from the normal setup, but you will be able to boot Windows from the Truecrypt rescue disk, into the Truecrypt passphrase prompt. 
(Don't bother with the'stealth' customized script where Truecrypt shows whatever 24 characters you choose, [e.g. 'Boot Error, No OS found' ], as it will be erased during Ububtu installation.)

Third, ( I haven't done this third part, as am not skilled enough ;-((  ),
Install a grub loader that has both Windows and Ubuntu boot loaders, into the third partition, and see if you can boot both Ubuntu and Windows from this third partition.
The Windows boot should get you to the Truecrypt passphrase prompt,

I have been successful with the first two parts but haven't been able to set up the third part.